# Mysql, Joining the columns with the same id's

Tags: mysql, join

Here are my tables. I want a query to join the `table1.score` and `table2.goal` with the `exam_id`. Is that possible?

```
table1
exam_id   score

 1          4
 1          5
 1          9
 1          10
 1          6
 1          9
 1          2
 1          10
```

They are exactly fitted when table1 and table 2 combine

```
 table2
 exam_id   goal
 1          1.1
 1          1.2
 1          1.3  
 1          1.4
 1          1.5
 1          1.6
 1          1.7
 1          1.8

desired output

exam_id   score     goal

 1          4        1.1
 1          5        1.2
 1          9        1.3 
 1          10       1.4 
 1          6        1.5       
 1          9        1.6 
 1          2        1.7 
 1          10       1.8
```

I use inner joins but it results to many rows and they are not exactly fitted to each other like the goal 1.8 must have score 10.

Comment: how will mysql know 1.8 must has score 10? you have one exam and all the scores and goals belong to it. Work on your design

Answer (score 0):

No.

Amongst other problems, the main problem here that stops this from being possible is that the *order* of the rows returned from a query that has no order by clause is indeterminate, and there is clearly no way to code an order by clause that would maintain the order you've presented.

If you could reliably order your rows, it would still be an ugly query, because mysql doesn't natively support row number, which you would have to join on.

Comment: Sorry, But I just did it. Thanks!

Comment: Unless there are other columns not shown that can give you reliable ordering, you only *think* you did it. Databases usually return rows in the order they were inserted, but there is no contract for this. This ordering will probably cease if you start deleting rows - later inserts may use the deleted rows storage and the unordered return order may change. Anyway, you should post your solution as an answer if you found one.